# Boundaries when printing list of lists

Tags: python, list

I have the following code:

```
matrix = [[0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1]]
```

I am able to print every line as follows using this:

```
for i in matrix:
    print(*i)
```

outputting:

```
0 0 1 0
1 1 0 0
0 0 0 1
1 0 0 1
```

I want to create custom boundaries for each line and I am able to do so with by manually adding the boundaries to the list of list as shown below:

```
for k in range(0,columns):
    matrix[k].insert(0,'[')
    matrix[k].insert(columns+1,']')
```

giving me the output as desired:

```
[ 0 0 1 0 ]
[ 1 1 0 0 ]
[ 0 0 0 1 ]
[ 1 0 0 1 ]
```

Is there a better way to do this, particularly without having to add the boundaries into my list?

Comment: You shouldl change the data just to print it.  You can just use `for i in matrix: print('[', *i, ']')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do it with two for loop like that

```
for i in matrix:
    s = "["
    for j in i:
        s = s + str(j) + " " 
    s = s + "]"
    print(s)
```

Or you can still do it with 1 for loop like that

```
for i in matrix:
    print("[", *i, "]")
```

Comment: Oh, I like yours better than mine.

Answer (score 0):

```
for row in matrhx:
    print( '[ ' + ' '.join(str(j)) + ' ]' )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for row in matrix:
    print(row)
```

*almost* does what you want, but it has commas. Replace those commas by nothing:

```
for row in matrix:
    print(str(row).replace(',',''))


[0 0 1 0]
[1 1 0 0]
[0 0 0 1]
[1 0 0 1]
```

Even this isn't *quite* what your target is, but in mathematical type-setting it is not customary to pad the boundaries of a matrix with white space.

Answer (score 0):

Another way with simple `list` to `str` casting and replacing all the **commas** with nothing like below-

```
matrix = [[0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1]]
for i in matrix:
    print(str(i).replace(',',''))
```

**DEMO**: https://rextester.com/QESAJC13339